# Azure Function System.IO.NotFoundException on Nuget Package dependency

Tags: c#, .net, azure, nuget, azure-functions

I am having an issue where my azure function is throwing the following exception when I run it locally.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient,
     Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its 
     dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Some information about my project:

- Azure function is targeting framework: .NET 4.6.1
- Nuget Package A is targeting fromework: .NET standard 1.3.
- Nuget Package A is also utilizing Nuget Package B, which is targeting framework: .NET standard 1.2
- Nuget Package B has the dependency on the Nuget Package System.Data.SqlClient 4.5.1

So in my Azure function, everything looks fine at compile time, but when I go to run the application and I get to the method call in Nuget Package A, I get the above exception.  I am noticing that if I create a Console Application that targets framework .NET 4.6.1, everything is working fine! (super confused).

So this leaves me to believe that there is some compatibility issue causing this in utilizing the Microsoft.NET.Sdk, but I have no found any similar issue as of yet.

This is the .csproj of my Azure Function:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.7.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="NugetPackageA" Version="1.0.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: v1 Azure function references `System.Data.SqlClient` in GAC by design, one suggestion is to delete `System.Data.SqlClient 4.5.1` installed with Nuget Package B if the version 4.5.1 is not actually required. Not sure whether it works as using package targets at .netstandard in v1(.net framework) is also suspicious.